# Create a "template" (format) string

Tags: c, string, printf, variadic-functions

I want to be able to create a template string and then use it like this:

```
int execute_command(char *cmd) {
  //...
}

char *template_command = "some_command %s some_args %s %d";
char *actual_command = template_command % (cmd1, arg1, 123);
// error, how do I do that?
int res = execute_command(actual_command);
```

Comment: Use `snprintf`, and remember to allocate enough space. Use `malloc` for that. POSIX `asnprintf` does that all for you, easy to define it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the maximum length of `actual_command`, then you can use either one of the following:

```
char actual_command[MAX_LEN+1];

// Option #1
sprintf(actual_command, template_command, cmd1, arg1, 123);

// Option #2
snprintf(actual_command, MAX_LEN+1, template_command, cmd1, arg1, 123);
```

---

If `MAX_LEN` is not defined correctly, then:

- Option #1 will result with undefined behavior (possibly runtime exception)
- Option #2 will result with incorrect result (contents of `actual_command`)

Answer (score 1):

Use `snprintf` and `malloc` (`snprint` returns the length of the string it would have written was the buffer only big enough, and receives the size of the buffer). POSIX `asnprintf` packages that nicely.
If you don't have it, define your own like this:

```
char* my_asnprintf(const char* format, ...) {
    va_list arg;
    va_start(arg, format);
    size_t n = 1 + vsnprintf((char*)format, 0, format, arg);
    va_end(arg);
    char* ret = malloc(n);
    if(!ret)
        return ret;
    va_start(arg, format);
    vsnprintf(ret, n, format, arg);
    va_end(arg);
    return ret;
}
```

Don't forget to `free` the buffer.